# How interspersed/intermixed arguments should be handled in argparse-module in versions prior to Python3.7?

Tags: python, argparse, optparse

When following the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#upgrading-optparse-code) for upgrading from `optparse` to `argparse` the following simple parser

```
import optparse
def parse_with_optparser(args):
    opt_parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    opt_parser.add_option('-a', action="store_true")
    return opt_parser.parse_args(args)
```

becomes:

```
def parse_with_argparser(args):
    arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    arg_parser.add_argument('-a', action="store_true")
    arg_parser.add_argument("sources", nargs='*')
    return arg_parser.parse_args(args)
```

i.e. an additional positional argument `sources` is added.

However, `optparse` supports interspersed (or intermixed in `argparse`-parlance)  arguments per default, i.e. we can call successful for

```
args = ['file1', '-a', 'file2']
parse_with_optparser(args) 
# ({'a': True}, ['file1', 'file2'])
```

but `argparse` doesn't support intermixed arguments and using it results in an error:

```
parse_with_argparser(args) 
# error: unrecognized arguments: file2
```

Since Python3.7 there is [`parse_intermixed_args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_intermixed_args) (instead of `parse_args`), which handles interspersed/intermixed arguments the same way as `optparse`. However, the framework targets Python2.7 and Pyton>=3.3 and thus using `parse_intermixed_args` doesn't cut it.

How interspersed/intermixed arguments should be handled in `argparse` in versions prior to Python3.7?

---

Some test cases:

```
      Input                         Output

['file1', 'file2', '-a']       Namespace(a=True, sources=['file1', 'file2'])
['-a', 'file1', 'file2']       Namespace(a=True, sources=['file1', 'file2'])
['file1', '-a', 'file2']       Namespace(a=True, sources=['file1', 'file2'])
['file1', '-a', '-b']          error (-b is unknown option)
```

Comment: I wrote the `intermixed` patch, and the could cite the relevant bug/issue.  The function (2 actually) is self contained, so could be copied from a 3.7 source.  The function comments explain how it works.  In `optparse` the positionals are leftovers.  `argparse` alternates parsing positionals and optionals, in the order they appear in `argv`.

Comment: In normal `argparse` parsing, `['file1', '-a', 'file2']`, 'file' is identified as a plain argument (non-flag), and is assigned to the `sources` Action.  It then parses '-a'.  There are no more unused actions to handle the 'file2', so it returns an error.  If 'file1' and 'file2' appear together, both are assigned to `sources`.

Comment: Your case is simple enough that `parse_known_args` may do what you want, returning both strings in the extras list.

Comment: @hpaulj you probably mean https://bugs.python.org/issue14191. I will go with your `parse_known_args`-suggestion, as for the code to work as it is `narg==SUPPRESS` must be handled correctly and this is not the case for Python<3.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've followed @hpaulj's advise and used [`parse_known_args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_known_args) to be able to handle intermixed options manually in a post processing step:

```
import argparse
def parse_with_argparser(args):
    arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    arg_parser.add_argument('-a', action="store_true")
    # thus, "sources" is also a part of the help-message:
    arg_parser.add_argument("sources", nargs='*')

    # collecting unknown-options for post processing,
    # rather than exiting directly:
    result, unknown = arg_parser.parse_known_args(args)

    # post processing:
    for x in unknown:
        # filter out unknown options (like -b)
        # exit with error
        if x.startswith('-'):
            arg_parser.error("unknown argument "+x)
        # that must be one of the remaining sources:
        getattr(result, 'sources').append(x)
    return result
```

It seems to be easier, than copying-and-pasting code for `parse_intermixed_args`, because `arparse` module cannot handle `narg==SUPPRESS` in Python<3.7 and it is needed for the patch.